# Benefits of using ref keyword

Tags: c#

I am just testing something and I’m wondering whether there is any benefit for using ref. 
So in the code below I have two methods both accept observablecollection of customer, one with a ref one without.
 Both do exactly the same (update the original list). So what is the advantage of using ref?

```
 ObservableCollection<Customer> customers;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer () { Id = 1, Name="Batman"},
            new Customer () { Id = 2, Name="Spiderman"},
        };

        AddCutomer(customers);
        AddCutomer(ref customers);
    }

    public void AddCutomer(ObservableCollection<Customer> customers)
    {
        customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 3, Name = "Superman" });
    }

    public void AddCutomer( ref ObservableCollection<Customer> customers)
    {
        customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 3, Name = "Superman" });
    }
```

If I use an int, then again it does not matter whether I use keyword ref or not, it changes the original value. However string behaves different depending on whether I use ref or not.

Kind Regards

Comment: If you find yourself using `ref` without fully understanding what it's used for, you probably don't need it.  I very, _very_ rarely use it.  Often you'll probably want to use `out` instead, if anything.

Comment: `ref` would be needed to update the variable `customers` defined in `MainWindow` inside the function `AddCustomer`. Since you aren't doing that you don't need `ref`.

Comment: Using ref allows you to change an object by setting it to a new instance. This is not the same as manipulate an object's properties within a sub. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: `int` will also "behave differently" depending on the presence of `ref` or not provided we're talking about changing parameter values inside the method called and observing the change outside or not.

Comment: Why down vote my question people?

Comment: Thank you for your answers to all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context: none at all. Ref passes a reference to the variable containing a reference to the instance, rather than copying the reference to the instance.

```
static void Main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    Foo(ref i);
    Console.WriteLine(i); // Should print 10
    Bar(j);
    Console.WriteLine(j); // Should print 2
}
static void Foo(ref int value)
{
    value = 10;
}
static void Bar(int value)
{
    value = 15;
}
```

`Foo` will change the value of `i` but Bar will not change the value of `j`.
Exact same behavior for reference types.

`ref` is most useful for structs. In most other cases `out` is preferred since it guarantees that the value is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ref` for Reference types allow you to do modify the reference itself, as oppose to the value it's pointing to.

Using your example, if you create a new ObservableCollection and assign it to the `customers` variable within your `AddCustomer` function, then the customers variable in the calling function `MainWindow` will now point to this new collection. I.e. the old collection will be lost.